# How pitch of a DNA Helix is 3.4 nm?

Tags: genetics, dna, molecular-genetics, human-genetics

[image]

How pitch of a [DNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA) [Helix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix) is 3.4 nm?

In the image that I have attached, the numbers with prime represent the number of base pair and normal numbers represent the number of gap elements between two base pairs. Everywhere to calculate the pitch (have 10 base pairs), number of base pairs (i.e. 10) is multiplied with length of gap element between two base pairs (i.e. 0.34 nm). BUT, to calculate pitch, the total number of gap elements should be multiplied with length of one gap element, Hence, the length of pitch should be 3.06 nm instead of 3.4 nm.

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange! No, you have to include a space around basepair when thinking about one repeating unit. Think about it this way: If one pitch contains 10 bp, then half a pitch contains 5 bp, and the length should be one half of the whole pitch, right? But this isn't compatible with your calculation, because $\frac12 \times 3.06\,{\rm nm} = 1.53\,{\rm nm} \neq 4\times 0.34\,{\rm nm}$. Perhaps it's [easier to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZzOj.jpg) why you have to count this way if you include half of space above and below.

Comment: @Domen "No, you have to include a space around basepair when thinking about one repeating unit"         Sir, with "space around basepair" do you mean the empty spaces left above bp 1' and below bp 10' (i used ' to show my numbering).

Comment: Those aren't empty spaces except in your diagram, they're the continuation of the chain in each direction.

Comment: i've tried to answer a related question here that somewhat includes this answer. https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/112909/calculating-pitch-of-b-dna/113805#113805