# Calculating pitch of B-DNA

Tags: genetics, dna

From this question ([How pitch of a DNA Helix is 3.4 nm?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/112728/75851)), I've learnt that for counting the **number** of axial rise for 10 base pairs in 1 helical turn to measure the pitch of B-DNA, we have to *include* the space above $1^{st}$ base pair and below $10^{th}$ base pair as per this image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZzOj.jpg

But now I'm confused as to why we include these spaces. Why do calculations fail if we were to measure starting from the base-pairs itself? Any help is valuable!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is mostly that you have to use the right denominator, as suggested by @DrRadium's comment.

The crucial mistake in the other answer was measuring 9bp and dividing by 10. That's measuring the length of 0.9bp, not 1bp.

You have chosen to measure the length of 9 base pairs and divide by 9. That works! you have shown that you get the right answer. In that case you don't need to add any space on either side.

In the other question, 9 base pairs were being measured, and then they were dividing by 10- *the distance between first and tenth bp* is not equal to *the length of 10bp*. The distance between the the $n$th and first basepair will $n-1$, or in this case $10-1 = 9$.

If you take the comment suggestion and add 1/2 on either side to your distance measurement, you are then measuring 10bp truly, so you'd better divide by 10.

So if you wanted to omit the space, you could measure the distance from the 1st to an 11th base pair. That would be 11-1=10bp long.

You may be interested in reading more about [0-based vs. 1-based indexing](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiwzJ-SsMeDAxUiJzQIHXigBawQFnoECB0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fanalytics-vidhya%2Farray-indexing-0-based-or-1-based-dd89d631d11c&usg=AOvVaw0MANPPSe6QUS-j_nkUjKr5&opi=89978449). This is an example of a classic "off-by-one" error that arises when you mix up the two indexing styles.